# Why is my int a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, int, typeerror

My code produces this error:

> ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

I have commented out the body of my code which doesn't have an impact what is causing the error.  The code is a section of a program I wrote to calculate Newton's Method.  I really do not know very much about pointers.  I am trying to avoid them right now.  All I want to do is stop my while loop if it runs too many times.

```
    int iter = 0;
    while (abs(nextValue - currValue) > 0.00000000001) and iter < 100000;
    {
//        currValue = nextValue;
//
//        double polyValue = 0;
//        int n3;
//        for (n3 = degree; n3 >= 0; n3--)
//        {
//            polyValue += coef[n3] * pow(currValue, n3);
//        }
//        double polynomial = polyValue;
//
//        polyValue = 0;
//        int n4;
//        for (n4 = degree; n4 >= 1; n4--)
//        {
//            polyValue += coef[n4] * n4 * pow(currValue, n4 - 1);
//        }
//        double polyPrime = polyValue;
//
//        nextValue = currValue - (polynomial / polyPrime);
        iter += 1;
    }
```

Comment: How do you declare `nextValue` and `currValue`?

Comment: Your `while` loop has too few parenthesis.

Comment: The while loop solved it.  So there must be something about the paren's that make iter a pointer.  Thank for that

Comment: No, the direct cause was `and iter` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `while` condition should probably read as:

```
while (abs(nextValue - currValue) > 0.00000000001 && iter < 100000)
```

Note that

1. There is no semicolon at the end.
2. The entire condition must be in parentheses.
3. `and` is replaced by `&&` - this is not strictly necessary because `and` is valid in C++ as far as I know, but I have never seen `and` being used in production code so far.